# API Gateway Websockets - Dealing with 10 minute idle connection timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I have simple chatroom application and if no users send any messages, the websocket closes after about 10 minutes. What is the best solution to keep the connection alive without reconnecting?

Answer (score 3):

It is always possible to send pings, the other side will have to reply with pong. ([proof](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2))

[This tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/creating-a-chat-app-with-serverless-websockets-and-python-a-tutorial-54cbc432e4f) might help you with that.

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing the link! I ended up making it so that the client would send interval pings every 9 mins. Do you know how I can access the lambda logs of the ping? It's not routed to apigateway's $default method so I'm not exactly sure where they are. The docs say "The /ping and /sping paths are reserved for the service health check." But I don't really understand how to use those paths to get the logs

Comment: @davids the paths `/ping` and `/sping` are reserved for internal use by the service (not at all a sensible design decision, but I digress).  This is unrelated to websocket pings.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Still can't find anything on how to get the ping logs :( if you have a link that would be great

Comment: @davids. You can see the logs of lambda separately. You need to  find your lambda in the web console, it will have a link to CloudWatch.

Comment: I've checked all the functions my websockets are linked to. $connect, $disconnect, $default, and my sendmessagefunction. The pings don't appear in any of them

Comment: @davids. the ping logs must be where the ping lambda function is defined, not on the API Gateway, but rather on Lambda section of the web console. [Link to CloudWatch](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home)

Comment: Yeah I checked every single one. When the ping happens nothing is logged into cloudwatch.

Comment: @davids. not sure how to help with that, sorry.

Comment: I have tried to implement a separate route for lambda to ping in order to keep the connection alive. It happens every 9 mins but unfortunately the connection is still timeout after the ping. How do you tell API Gateway that the connection is not idle?

Comment: @Kong no idea. I gave up trying to implement it.

Comment: You will probably need to use the [@connections interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html) (also known as the API Gateway Management API) to send unrequested messages to the client. You'll probably need some sort of connection tracking to make this work, though.

Comment: Ping/Pong is not for preventing timeouts, it is for detecting them.  Ping says "Hello are you there?" and a Pong replies "Yes I am here".  This link describes how to add a health check for the service to detect when it is down.  But you want to do a regular ping message down a socket, not http.  Since browsers hide the ping implementation deeper down the stack, the only option from the client is to send your own keepalive heartbeat message that is regularly sent down the socket (not a ping).  Handle that message with a lambda and you can see it in your logs like any other message.