# C# WPF Socket gets disconnected automatically. Why?

Tags: c#, sockets, disconnect

I am working on one project that allows clients and server communicate asynchronous.
Everything works perfectly fine. But by some reason if client is online for 10 or 15 minutes, it gets forcefully disconnected by the host. And it happens when I am trying to send a string to the server after 10 or 15 minutes.

**Client Log file:**

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at TalkCentre.Main.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.b__0()

System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at TalkCentre.Main.SendString(String text)

**Server Log File:**

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at TalkCentreServer.Program.ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)

When I make exception, it looks like it appears in this code in SERVER:

```
    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int received;
        try
        {
            received = current.EndReceive(AR);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.RemoteEndPoint + " Client forcefully disconnected");
            // Don't shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway.
            current.Close();
            clientSockets.Remove(current);
            return;
        }
        byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
        if (text.ToLower() == "connected") // Client requested time
        {
            foreach (Socket connectedUsers in clientSockets)
            {
                string _eachConnection = ("Connected- " + current.RemoteEndPoint).ToString();
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_eachConnection);
                Socket socket = (Socket)connectedUsers;
                socket.Send(data);
                Console.WriteLine(socket.RemoteEndPoint + " Is Online");
            }
        }
        current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
    }
```

I am pretty sure that it is not a duplicate as this issue is C# WPF related. And this issue doesn't occur when trying to connect. But only after 10 or 15 minutes when sending string.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58401092/api-gateway-websockets-dealing-with-10-minute-idle-connection-timeout help?

Comment: What do you mean with "*C# WPF related*"? Would the problem not occur in a VB.NET WinForms application?

Comment: @mjwills No, I've seen this before, and this case is not related to mine. But thanks for fast respond.

Comment: @Clemens When I say C# WPF it means that WPF platform has different type of requirements for using sockets. Issues that appear in WinForms or VB.NET are so much different. Resolution for this problem would have so much different approach.

Comment: What "*different type of requirements for using sockets*" exactly? There is nothing WPF specific in your question.

Comment: In my example server is in console app of course. Client is WPF based.

Comment: @Clemens Ok, maybe I shouldn't mention word 'WPF' but the fact is that I have an issue in server side that is a  pure C# console app that needs some attention. I just need your suggestion what am I doing wrong in my code.

Comment: I was just thinking, should I maybe disclude catch (SocketException) ?