# Websocket auto reopen ping vs close codes

Tags: websocket, aws-api-gateway

So I have this very common issue where I have to open a ws connection and keep it open.

I have the following to handle errors using close codes:

```js
ws.onerror = () => {
  ws.close(3000, 'unexpected');
};

ws.onclose = ({ code }) => {
  if (code !== 1000) {
    ws = new Websocket(...
  }
}
```

So this should reopen my socket on any error, and when i reach the idle timeout (Gateway API is closing with code 1001).
It should also allow me to close the socket using `ws.close(1000)`.

However, [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58401092/api-gateway-websockets-dealing-with-10-minute-idle-connection-timeout) (and collegues) suggests using a ping-pong instead.
When browsing the subject i realised this is a standard way of doing this.

I think the first solution is simpler so why isn't it more documented, are there pitfalls I didn't see using this method ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using AWS AppSync to deal with web sockets on your AWS API gateways.

They periodically send a "ka" (short for keep alive) and you can configure it to stop on certain events.

> "AWS AppSync sends "ka" messages periodically. The client keeps track
> of the time that it received each "ka" message. If the client doesn't
> receive a "ka" message within connectionTimeoutMs milliseconds, the
> client should close the connection."

Comment: Hi @abo and thanks for the answer, but the question is more about why the close codes thing isn't more used than it is.
I think AWS AppSync is a little overkill to handle something like a ping-pong.